# Delphi FFMPEG CUDA hardware accelerated video decoding generating shadows

Tags: delphi, ffmpeg, hardware, decoding

I'm trying to use cuda hardware accelerated video decoding, loading from a .mp4 file, according to the code bellow, but [getting the image with shadows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rekZY.png)

Specification:
FFMPEG 4.3
Delphi 10.3
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU 4Gb DDR6
Intel Core i5 11400H 16 Gb RAM

```
unit UVideoDecoding;

interface

uses
  Vcl.Graphics, Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  libavcodec,  libavdevice,
  libavfilter, libswresample, libavformat, libavutil,
  libswscale;

type
  TDecoder = class
  protected
    fFormatCtx: PAVFormatContext;
    fCodec: PAVCodec;
    fCodecParams, fLocalCodecParams: PAVCodecParameters;
    fCodecCtx: libavcodec.PAVCodecContext;
    fPacket: PAVPacket;
    fFrameIn, fFrameOut: PAVFrame;
    fScaler: PSwsContext;
    fVideoStreamIndex: Integer;
    fHWPixelFormat: AVPixelFormat;
    fOutputWidth: Integer;
    fOutputHeight: Integer;

    function DecodeVideoPacket: Integer;
  public
    function Load(pFileName: string): Integer;

  end;
implementation

function TDecoder.Load(pFileName: string): Integer;
var
  vCount: Integer;
  vLocalCodec: PAVCodec;
  vFileName: AnsiString;
  vType: AVHWDeviceType;
  vDecPackResponse: Integer;
begin

  vType := av_hwdevice_find_type_by_name('cuda');
  {vType = AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_CUDA}

  fFormatCtx := avformat_alloc_context;

  vFileName := AnsiString(pFileName);
  avformat_open_input(fFormatCtx, PAnsiChar(vFileName), nil, nil);

  avformat_find_stream_info(fFormatCtx, nil);

  for vCount := 0 to fFormatCtx.nb_streams - 1 do
  begin
    fLocalCodecParams := fFormatCtx.streams[vCount].codecpar;

    case fLocalCodecParams.codec_id of
      AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_H264: vLocalCodec := avcodec_find_decoder_by_name('h264_cuvid');
      AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC: vLocalCodec := avcodec_find_decoder_by_name('hevc_cuvid');
      AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_MJPEG: vLocalCodec := avcodec_find_decoder_by_name('mjpeg_cuvid');
      AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4: vLocalCodec := avcodec_find_decoder_by_name('mpeg4_cuvid');
      else
      vLocalCodec := avcodec_find_decoder(fLocalCodecParams.codec_id);
    end;

    if fLocalCodecParams.codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO then
    begin
      fVideoStreamIndex := vCount;
      fCodec := vLocalCodec;
      fCodecParams := fLocalCodecParams;
    end;
  end;

  {fCodec.name = h264_cuvid}  

  fCodecCtx := avcodec_alloc_context3(fCodec);


  var vHWDeviceCtx: PAVBufferRef;
  try
    if av_hwdevice_ctx_create(vHWDeviceCtx, vType, nil, nil, 0) >= 0 then
      fCodecCtx.hw_device_ctx := av_buffer_ref(vHWDeviceCtx);
  finally
    av_buffer_unref(vHWDeviceCtx);
  end;

  avcodec_open2(fCodecCtx, fCodec, nil);
  {
    fCodecCtx.codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264
    fCodecCtx.pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_MMAL
  }

  fFrameIn := av_frame_alloc;
  fFrameOut := av_frame_alloc;
  fFrameOut.format := Integer(AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA);
  fFrameOut.width  := 640;
  fFrameOut.height := 480;

//On getting sws_context I've tried srcFormat = AV_PIX_FMT_MMAL but the result was nil
  fScaler := sws_getContext(fCodecCtx.Width, fCodecCtx.Height, AV_PIX_FMT_NV12{fCodecCtx.pix_fmt},
    fOutputWidth, fOutputHeight, AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA, SWS_BILINEAR, nil, nil, nil);

  fPacket := av_packet_alloc;

  while (av_read_frame(fFormatCtx, fPacket) >= 0) do
  begin
    if fPacket.stream_index = fVideoStreamIndex then
    begin
      vDecPackResponse := DecodeVideoPacket;

      av_packet_unref(fPacket);

      if vDecPackResponse < 0 then
        Break;
    end
  end;

  Exit(0);
end;  

function TDecoder.DecodeVideoPacket: Integer;
var
  vResponse: Integer;
  vBmp: Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap;
  vScaleResult, vSize: Integer;
  vBuffer: PByte;
  vSWFrame, vTMPFrame: pAVFrame;
begin
  Result := 0;

  vResponse := avcodec_send_packet(fCodecCtx, fPacket);

  if vResponse < 0 then
    Exit(vResponse);

  while (vResponse >= 0) do
  begin
    vResponse := avcodec_receive_frame(fCodecCtx, fFrameIn);
    if (vResponse = AVERROR_EAGAIN) or (vResponse = AVERROR_EOF) then
      Break
    else if vResponse < 0 then
      Exit(vResponse);

    if vResponse >= 0 then
    begin
      vSWFrame := av_frame_alloc;

      if av_hwframe_transfer_data(vSWFrame, fFrameIn, 0) >= 0 then
        vTMPFrame := vSWFrame
      else
        vTMPFrame := fFrameIn;

      vSize := av_image_get_buffer_size(AVPixelFormat(vTMPFrame.format), vTMPFrame.width, vTMPFrame.height, 1);
      vBuffer := av_malloc(vSize);

      if Assigned(vBuffer) then
        av_image_copy_to_buffer(vBuffer, vSize, @vTMPFrame.data, @vTMPFrame.linesize, AVPixelFormat(vTMPFrame.format), vTMPFrame.width, vTMPFrame.height, 1);

      MoveMemory(vTMPFrame.data[0], vBuffer, vSize);

      vTMPFrame.data[0] := vTMPFrame.data[0] + vTMPFrame.linesize[0] * (fCodecCtx.height - 1);
      vTMPFrame.linesize[0] := vTMPFrame.linesize[0] * -1;
      vTMPFrame.data[1] := vTMPFrame.data[1] + vTMPFrame.linesize[1] * (fCodecCtx.height div 2 - 1);
      vTMPFrame.linesize[1] := vTMPFrame.linesize[1] * -1;
      vTMPFrame.data[2] := vTMPFrame.data[2] + vTMPFrame.linesize[2] * (fCodecCtx.height div 2 - 1);
      vTMPFrame.linesize[2] := vTMPFrame.linesize[2] * -1;

      vScaleResult := sws_scale(fScaler, @vTMPFrame.Data, @vTMPFrame.Linesize, 0,
        fCodecCtx.Height, @fFrameOut.data, @fFrameOut.Linesize);
      if vScaleResult <= 0 then
      begin
        Break;
      end;

      vBmp := Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.Create;
      try
        vBmp.Height := fOutputHeight;
        vBmp.Width := fOutputWidth;
        vBmp.PixelFormat := TPixelFormat.pf32bit;

        MoveMemory(PByte(vBmp.ScanLine[vBmp.Height -1]),
          fFrameOut.data[0], fOutputHeight * fFrameOut.linesize[0]);

//Renders BMP on main thread
//        if Assigned(fOnBitmap) then
//          fOnBitmap(vBmp);
      finally
        av_frame_unref(vSWFrame);
        av_frame_free(vTMPFrame);
        av_freep(@vBuffer);
        FreeAndNil(vBmp);
        Result := 1;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

I've tried using different pixelformats but none of them properly decoded the video.